# A interesting improper integral, $ \int_{0}^1\frac{\ln x}{x^2-x-1}\text{d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

$$\displaystyle \int_{0}^1\frac{\ln x}{x^2-x-1}\text{d}x$$

I think there should be a smart way to evaluate this. But I cant see..

Comment: Could you please elaborate on why you find this integral interesting?

Comment: It converges to $\dfrac{\pi^2}{5 \sqrt{5}}$ according to Mathematica.  To just see that it does converge it suffices to note that the denominator is bounded below in absolute value by a positive number, and $\int_0^1\ln(x)dx$ converges, e.g. by comparison (in absolute value) with $\frac{1}{\sqrt x}$ near $x=0$.

Comment: This integral is given by my teacher, I run it on Maple, it does converge.

Comment: Have you tried partial fractions and series expansions?

Comment: @Ryan: Yes. I think the integral may be evaluated elementarily. Chris.

Comment: This integral is a special case of the [more general problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188732/methods-to-evaluate-int-a-b-frac-ln-left-tx-u-right-mx/188828#188828).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using a partial fraction decomposition, one can write
$$
\frac{1}{x^2-x-1}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}\left[\frac{1}{x-x_+}-\frac{1}{x-x_-}\right],
$$
where $x_{\pm}=\frac{1}{2}\left(1\pm\sqrt{5}\right)$ are the roots of the polynomial $x^2-x-1$.

We now observe that we have the uniformly convergent series expansions
$$
\frac{1}{x-x_+} = -\frac{1}{x_+}\sum_{n=0}^\infty{\left(\frac{x}{x_+}\right)^n},\quad 0<x<1;
$$
$$
\frac{1}{x-x_-} = -\frac{1}{x_-}\sum_{n=0}^\infty{\left(\frac{x}{x_-}\right)^n},\quad 0<x<-x_-;
$$
and
$$
\frac{1}{x-x_-} = \frac{1}{x}\sum_{n=0}^\infty{\left(\frac{x_-}{x}\right)^n},\quad -x_-<x<1.
$$
Putting this together, one obtains
$$
\int_0^1\frac{\log(x)}{x^2-x-1}d\,x = \frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}\times\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left[-\frac{1}{x_+}\int_0^1{\log(x)\left(\frac{x}{x_+}\right)^nd\,x} + \frac{1}{x_-}\int_0^{-x_-}{\log(x)\left(\frac{x}{x_-}\right)^n d\,x} - \int_{-x_-}^1{\frac{1}{x}\log(x)\left(\frac{x_-}{x}\right)^n d\,x}\right].
$$

I'll leave the rest of the computations to the OP, but can expand if necessary.

The final result is $\pi^2/5\sqrt{5}$, as has already been mentioned.

Comment: Wow! very sharp! Thank you! : )

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{{\displaystyle #1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sr}[2]{\,\,\,\stackrel{{#1}}{{#2}}\,\,\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
& \color{#44f}{\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{x} \over x^{2} - x - 1}\dd x} =
\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{x} \over \pars{x - \phi}\pars{x + \phi^{-1}}}\dd x
\end{align}
where $\ds{\phi \equiv \pars{1 + \root{5}}/2}$ is the *Golden Ratio*.

Then,
\begin{align}
& \color{#44f}{\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{x} \over x^{2} - x - 1}\dd x} =
-\,{\root{5} \over 5}\bracks{{\tt I}\pars{\phi} -
{\tt I}\pars{-\,{1 \over \phi}}}
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
\left.\rule{0pt}{5mm}{\tt I}\pars{a}\right\vert_{a\ \not\in\ \bracks{0,1}}\,\,\, & \equiv \int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{x} \over a - x}\dd x
\sr{x/a\ \mapsto\ x}{=}
\int_{0}^{1/a}{\ln\pars{ax} \over 1 - x}\dd x
\\[5mm] & \sr{\rm IBP}{=}
\int_{0}^{1/a}\ \overbrace{{\ln\pars{1 - x} \over x}}^{\ds{-\on{Li}_{2}'\pars{x}}}\ \dd x = -\on{Li}_{2}\pars{1 \over a}
\end{align}
$\ds{\on{Li}_{s}}$ is the *order*-$\ds{s}$ *Polylogarithm Function*. Therefore,
\begin{align}
& \color{#44f}{\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{x} \over x^{2} - x - 1}\dd x} =
-\,{\root{5} \over 5}\bracks{-\on{Li}_{2}\pars{1 \over \phi} + \on{Li}_{2}\pars{-\phi}}
\\[5mm] = & \ \bbx{\color{#44f}{{\root{5} \over 25}\pi^{2}}} \approx 0.8828 \\ &
\end{align}
$\ds{\on{Li}_{2}\pars{1/\phi}}$ and $\ds{\on{Li}_{2}\pars{-\phi}}$ are
given, for example, [in this site](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm#Dilogarithm).

Comment: Ironically you answered after 10 yrs :) Btw why $a \not\in [0,1]$?