# Hard Integral $\int_0^1 \frac{\arctan{x}}{x^2+x+1} \, \mathrm{d}x$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I'm trying to find closed form of this integral
$$\mathcal{I} = \int_0^1 \frac{\arctan{x}}{x^2+x+1} \, \mathrm{d}x$$

I tried it by using differentiation integral sign, partial fraction but nothing seems to work.
I was thinking to rewrite the denominator as
$$\mathcal{I} =  \int_0^1 \frac{(1-x)\arctan{x}}{1-x^3} \, \mathrm{d}x$$
And after using geometric series I got
$$\mathcal{I} = \int_0^1 \left( \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{3n} \right)(1-x)\arctan{x} \, \mathrm{d}x$$

We can interchange integral sign and summation because $x^{3n}$ is uniformly convergent in $0$ to $1$,

$$\mathcal{I} =  \sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_0^1(x^{3n}-x^{3n+1})\arctan{x} \, \mathrm{d}x$$

Now after doing this I am thinking I have made the problem more harder...

I feel that this integral should have a closed form as this integral has
$$\int_0^1 \frac{\arctan{x}}{x^2+1} \, \mathrm{d}x = \frac{\pi^2}{32}$$

That's how I thought...
Thank you very much!!

Comment: Here is a similar integral, that might give you some ideas: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3105528/42969

Comment: @MartinR yeah, I am going to find that's closed form first. Thank you :)

Comment: Your analogous integral is quite trivial, as it’s $\int u\,du$. That doesn’t get you very far unless you have a formula for $\arctan(x+c)$.

Comment: @TedShifrin exactly, I am also thinking about integrals of the form $$\int_0^1 \frac{\arctan(x+a)}{x^2+b^2} \, \mathrm{d}x$$ $\mathcal{I}$ can be transformed into this form I guess..

Comment: Mathematica produces an analytic expression with $\text{PolyLog}$s.

Comment: [integral-calculator.com](https://www.integral-calculator.com/#expr=arctan%28x%29%20%2F%20%28x%5E2%20%2B%20x%20%2B%201%29) actually finds an antiderivative with products and sums of polylogarithms and complex logarithms including a step-by-step derivation.

Comment: @KevinDietrich The issue is that using the option to integrate from 0 to 1 yields a negative number, even though the integrand is always positive

Comment: The same integral is evaluated [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3340907/how-to-evaluate-int-0-infty-frac-arctan-xx2x1dx), but over $[0,\infty)$

Comment: Maple does it using dilog.  This comes from writing $$\arctan \! \left(x \right) = (\ln(1-ix) - \ln(1+ix)) i/2$$
 and expanding $1/(x^2+x+1)$ in partial fractions.  In general, $$\int \frac{\ln(x-a)}{x-b}\; dx = \text{dilog}\left(\frac{x-b}{a-b}\right) + \ln(x-a) \ln\left(\frac{x-b}{a-b}\right) + C$$

Comment: @KevinDietrich Isn't it returning a horrifying answer... what else you think about it?

Comment: @RobertIsrael but $x^2+x+1$ have imaginary roots...... we can write it as $$x^2+x+1 = \left( x + \frac{1}{2} - \frac{\sqrt{3}i}{2} \right)\left( x + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{3}i}{2} \right)$$

Comment: @LuckyChouhan [Complex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number), not imaginary. Yes, $a$ and $b$ can be complex numbers.