# Two Euler sums each containing the reciprocal of the central binomial coefficient

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, harmonic-numbers, euler-sums

> Is it possible to find closed-form expressions for the following two Euler sums containing the reciprocal of the central binomial coefficient? 
>   $$1. \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n H_n}{(2n + 1) \binom{2n}{n}} \qquad \text{and} \qquad 2. \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n H_{2n + 1}}{(2n + 1) \binom{2n}{n}}$$
>   Here $H_n$ is the $n$th *harmonic number*.

The reason I am interested in these two sums is as follows. It arose while considering alternative ways to evaluate the integral given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/266957/a-interesting-improper-integral-int-01-frac-ln-xx2-x-1-textdx)
$$\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x}{x^2 - x - 1} \, dx = \frac{\pi^2}{5 \sqrt{5}}.$$

One way, very similar to the answer given, is to use the dilogarithm machinery and is relatively simple.

A second way is as follows:
\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x}{x^2 - x - 1} \, dx &= - \int_0^1 \frac{\ln x}{1 + (x - x^2)} \, dx\\
&= - \int_0^1 \ln x \sum_{n = 0}^\infty (-1)^n (x - x^2)^n \, dx \tag1 \\
&= - \sum_{n = 0}^\infty (-1)^n \int_0^1 \ln x \, x^n (1 - x)^n \, dx\tag2.
\end{align}
In (1) a geometric expansion has been used and is valid since $|x - x^2| < 1$ for $0 < x < 1$. In (2) the summation and integration has been interchanged and is valid due to the dominated convergence theorem.

Consider
$$J(a) = \int_0^1 x^a (1 - x)^n \, dx, \quad a > 0.$$
Differentiating with respect to $a$ we have
$$J'(a) = \int_0^1 \ln x \, x^a (1 - x)^n \, dx,$$
and we observe that
$$J'(n) = \int_0^1 \ln x \, x^n (1 - x)^n \, dx.$$

Now
$$J(a) = \operatorname{B} (a + 1, n + 1) = \frac{\Gamma (n + 1) \Gamma (a + 1)}{\Gamma (a + n + 2)}.$$
Thus
$$J' (a) = \frac{\Gamma (n + 1) \Gamma (a + 1)}{\Gamma (a + n + 2)} \left [\psi (a + 1) - \psi (a + n + 2) \right ].$$
Here $\psi (z)$ is the [digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function). Setting $a = n$ then gives
$$J'(n) = \frac{1}{(2n + 1) \binom{2n}{n}} \left [\psi (n + 1) - \psi (2n + 2) \right ] = \frac{1}{(2n + 1) \binom{2n}{n}} (H_n - H_{2n + 1}),$$
where we have used the [result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Relation_to_harmonic_numbers): $\psi(x) = H_{n - 1} - \gamma$, with $\gamma$ corresponding the the Euler–Mascheroni constant.

So on returning to our integral we see that
$$\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x}{x^2 - x - 1} \, dx = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n + 1) \binom{2n}{n}} (H_{2n + 1} - H_n) = \frac{\pi^2}{5 \sqrt{5}},$$
and brings me to the two Euler sums.

---

*Thoughts on finding the sums*

One thought is to somehow massage the result
$$\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{x^{2n + 2}}{(n + 1)(2n + 1) \binom{2n}{n}} = 4 \arcsin^2 \left (\frac{x}{2} \right ),$$
in conjunction with perhaps the result
$$H_n = - n \int_0^1 x^{n - 1} \ln (1 - x) \, dx,$$
into a suitable form but the presence of the alternating term $(-1)^n$ is proving difficult.

Comment: It may or may not be of much use, but $$H_n=\int_0^1\frac{x^{n}-1}{x-1}dx$$

Comment: I'm not sure why you're calling these "Euler sums". They don't look like anything at http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerSum.html Maybe "Apery-like sums" would be closer to standard practice, as in https://www.math.arizona.edu/~rta/001/sherman.travis/series.pdf

Comment: @Gerry Myerson I think of an *Euler sum* as an infinite sum that involves the harmonic number $H_n$ or its generalisation $H^{(k)}_n$.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://www.pi314.net/eng/hypergse13.php#x15-14400013.4) could be of help $(13.4.2)$. At least the sum you denoted as $1.$ appeared there even though it is not explicitely evaluated but used in order to evalutate a slightly different sum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT 12.02.2019**

Inspired by the comment of omegadot "Based on the numerical evidence it seems correct with the final two expressions being far more complicated than I could have ever imagined. I am guessing it would also be an almighty herculean task to finally show $p_2-p_1 = \frac{\pi^2}{5\sqrt{5}}$"

I have solved both problems (without being Hercules).

First I showed, starting from my expressions $(2c)$ and $(3c)$, that indeed

$$p_2-p_1 = \frac{\pi^2}{5\sqrt{5}}\tag{e1}$$

Then simplifying $p_1$ using the identity mentioned in my comment

$$\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)+\text{Li}_2(z)+\frac{1}{2} \log ^2(-z)+\zeta (2)=0, z\lt 0\tag{e2}$$

and using $(e1)$ for $p_2$ I find with

$$q=\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{5}-1\right)=\frac{1}{\phi}\tag{e3}$$

these simplified expressions (using $q$ or the golden ratio $\phi$, alternatively)

$$p_1 = \frac{4}{\sqrt{5}} \;\text{Li}_2\left(-q^2\right)+\frac{4 \log (q) \log (5 q)}{\sqrt{5}}+\frac{\pi ^2}{3 \sqrt{5}}\tag{2e}$$

$$p_1 = -\frac{4 \text{Li}_2\left(-\phi ^2\right)}{\sqrt{5}}-\frac{4 \log (\phi ) \log (5 \phi )}{\sqrt{5}}-\frac{\pi ^2}{3 \sqrt{5}}\tag{2f}$$

$$p_2 = \frac{4}{\sqrt{5}} \;\text{Li}_2\left(-q^2\right)+\frac{4 \log (q) \log (5 q)}{\sqrt{5}}+\frac{8 \pi ^2}{15 \sqrt{5}}\tag{3e}$$

$$p_2 = -\frac{4 \text{Li}_2\left(-\phi ^2\right)}{\sqrt{5}}-\frac{4 \log (\phi ) \log (5 \phi )}{\sqrt{5}}-\frac{2 \pi ^2}{15 \sqrt{5}}\tag{3f}$$

*Remark*

Observing that the parameter $q$ solves the equation $x^2+x-1=0$ led me to study the integral

$$i_2= \int_0^1 \frac{\log(x)}{x^2+x-1}\,dx\tag{e4}$$

which is similar to the integral

$$i_1= \int_0^1 \frac{\log(x)}{x^2-x-1}\,dx$$

which was the starting point in the post of omegadot.

I solved the (divergent) integral $i_2$ with a limiting procedure starting from a general polynomial of 2nd degree in the denominator which gives the result

$$i_2 = \frac{3 \pi ^2}{10 \sqrt{5}}+\frac{i \pi  \log (q)}{\sqrt{5}}\tag{e5}$$

The real part is the principal value of $i_2$.

Note that this expression resembles the constant terms in $p_{1,2}$.

**Original post, 11.02.2019**

The question was "Is it possible to find closed-form expressions for the following two Euler sums containing the reciprocal of the central binomial coefficient?"

The answer is yes, and we provide both closed expressions.

These are given in both cases in terms of combinations of $\log(.)$ and the polylog function $\text{Li}_2(.)$. The arguments are expressions of the type $a + b \sqrt{5}$ with rational $a$ and $b$ where $\sqrt{5}$ can also be expressed in terms of the golden ratio.

**Definitions**

$$p_1= \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n H_n}{(2n + 1) \binom{2n}{n}} \qquad \text{and} \qquad p_2= \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n H_{2n + 1}}{(2n + 1) \binom{2n}{n}}$$

Here $H_n$ is the $n$th *harmonic number*.

**Results**

Using

$$H_{n}=\int_0^1 \frac{1-x^n}{1-x} \, dx\tag{1}$$

I find

*For $p_1$*

The sum under the integral is

$$s_1 = \frac{4 \left(\sqrt{5} \sqrt{x} \sqrt{x+4}\; \text{arcsinh}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-5\; \text{arcsinh}\left(\frac{\sqrt{x}}{2}\right)\right)}{5 (1-x) \sqrt{x} \sqrt{x+4}}\tag{2a}$$

We have to evaluate the integral

$$p_1 = \int_0^1 s_1 \,dx \tag{2b}$$

This can also be done in Mathematica to give

$$p_1 =-\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}} \left(\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{2} \left(-3-\sqrt{5}\right)\right)-\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{2} \left(-3+\sqrt{5}\right)\right)\tag{2c}\\+\log (25) \log \left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)\right)$$

Numerically,

$$N(p_1) \simeq -0.12711517793300195$$

Notice that $p_1$ can also be expressed by the "golden ratio

$$\phi=\frac{1}{2}(1+\sqrt{5}) \simeq 1.618033988749895$$

as

$$p_1=-\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}} (-\text{Li}_2(\phi -2)+\text{Li}_2(-\phi -1)+4 \log (2 \phi -1) \log (\phi ))\tag{2d}$$

*For $p_2$*

the sum can be done

$$s_2 = \frac{1}{1-x} \sum_{n = 0}^\infty (-1)^n (1-x^{2n + 1})\frac{1}{(2n + 1) \binom{2n}{n}}\\= \frac{4 \left(\sqrt{5} \sqrt{x^2+4} \;\text{arcsinh}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-5 \; \text{arcsinh}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)}{5 (1-x) \sqrt{x^2+4}}\tag{3a}$$

We have to evaluate the integral.

$$p_2 = \int_0^1 s_2 \,dx\tag{3b}$$

Mathematica 8.0 can do the integral (version 10.1 can't, so it is advisable to keep older versions).

The result (obtained after long series of surprising simplifications)

$$p_2 = \frac{4 \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{7}{2}-\frac{3 \sqrt{5}}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{5}}-\frac{4 \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{2} \left(-3+\sqrt{5}\right)\right)}{\sqrt{5}}+\frac{2 \log \left(\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{5}-1\right)\right) \log \left(25 \left(9-4 \sqrt{5}\right)\right)}{\sqrt{5}}\tag{3c}$$

Numerically,

$$N(p_2) \simeq 0.7556490761416742$$

In Terms of the golden ratio we have

$$p_2 = \frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}(\log (\phi -1) \log (25 (13-8 \phi ))-2 \text{Li}_2(\phi -2)+2 \text{Li}_2(5-3 \phi ))\tag{3d}$$

**Technical remarks**

Doing the integrals in Mathematica was by no means trivial. I proceeded in the common manner to calculate first the antiderivative and then - after having numerically confirmed continuity - take the limits at $x=0$ and $x=1$, resp.

While Version 10.1 refused to calculate the Limits at $x=1$, Version 8.0 provided results but they contained spurious imaginary parts and terms with products of concealed $0 * \infty$ so that the command "Simplify" returned "Indeterminate". A heuristic mixture of numerical checks and tetative cancelleations finally led me to the expressions given which were finally justified numerically.

Comment: Based on the numerical evidence it seems correct with the final two expressions being far more complicated than I could have ever imagined. I am guessing it would also be an almighty herculean task to finally show $p_2 - p_1 = \frac{\pi^2}{5 \sqrt{5}}$. Nice job.

Comment: @ omagadot You are right, it seems to be hard to prove the simple result for the difference starting from my expressions. Dropping the $(-1)^{n}$ in the sums, and calling them $q$ I find $q_2 - q_1 = \frac{4}{3} \sqrt{3} \Im\left(\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{4} \left(1+i \sqrt{3}\right)\right)\right)+\frac{1}{9} \left(\sqrt{3} \pi \right) \log (4)+\frac{1}{9} \left(\psi ^{(1)}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)-\psi ^{(1)}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)\right) \simeq 1.17195 $

Comment: @ omegadot In trying to find simplifications I discovered this interesting relation valid for $z\lt 0$: $\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)+\text{Li}_2(z)+\frac{1}{2} \log ^2(-z)+\zeta (2)=0$. It is most probably known.

Comment: @ omegadot I have continued the simplification in an edit. I thank you for accepting my answer but I'd like to ask you to reopen the question for further discussion.

Comment: Thanks to the upvoters, but interestingly the problem gets a much higher reputation (7 Points) than the solution (2 points). So IMHO "reputation" seems to be a different measure than "appreciation". But English is not my native language ...

Comment: Thanks for all your hard work on this problem. It is greatly appreciated. I accepted and upvoted your answer and hope others reading it would think the same.

Comment: Thank you, omegadot. I didnt mean you, of course. I was sursprised that although many upvoted your interesting question only one responded, and we two remained "entre nous".