# Generalized logarithm integral $\int^1_0 \frac{\log(1+x)}{1+a^2x^2}\, dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

How to prove that

$$\int^1_0 \frac{\log(1+x)}{1+a^2x^2}\, dx= \frac{1}{a} \Im \left( \chi_2(ia) - \operatorname{Li}_2\left( \frac{1+ai}{2}\right)\right)\,\,\, a> 0$$

where $\Im $ is the imaginary part , 
$\chi$ is the Legendre chi function , $\operatorname{Li}_2$ is the dilogarithm .

For the special case $a=1$ we have

$$\int^1_0 \frac{\log(1+x)}{1+x^2}dx = \frac{\pi}{8}\log(2)$$

Comment: Your problem is a special case of [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188732/methods-to-evaluate-int-a-b-frac-ln-left-tx-u-right-mx/188828#188828).

Comment: When $a = 2$, $\mbox{LHS} \approx 0.1617$, $\mbox{RHS} \approx 0.2220$. However, they agree when $a = 1$.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal Please, check my above comment. I guess the proposed OP answer is wrong.

Comment: @FelixMarin: Let me check this later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{1 + x} \over 1 + a^{2}x^{2}}\,\dd x:\ {\large ?}.\qquad
     a \in {\mathbb R}}$.

> I believe the proposed OP solution $\ds{\pars{~{1 \over a}\,\Im\pars{\chi_2\pars{\ic a}
>       -{\rm Li}_{2}\pars{1\ +\ a\ic \over 2}}~}}$ is not correct. Albeit it agrees at
>   $\ds{a = 1}$, we can evaluate it for several values and they yield different values between LHS and RHS.

\begin{align}&\color{#c00000}{\int_{0}^{1}%
{\ln\pars{1 + x} \over 1 + a^{2}x^{2}}\,\dd x}
=\Im\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{1 + x} \over -\ic + \verts{a}x}\,\dd x
=\Im\int_{1}^{2}{\ln\pars{x} \over -\ic - \verts{a} + \verts{a}x}\,\dd x
\\[3mm]&=\Im\bracks{-\,{1 \over 1 + \ic\verts{a}}
\int_{1}^{2}{\ln\pars{x} \over 1 - \verts{a}x/\pars{\ic + \verts{a}}}\,\dd x}
\\[3mm]&=\Im\bracks{-\,{1 \over 1 + \ic\verts{a}}
\int_{1}^{2}{\ln\pars{x} \over 1 - \mu x}\,\dd x}\,,
\qquad\qquad
\mu \equiv {\verts{a} \over \ic + \verts{a}}
\end{align}

> With
>   $\ds{\mu x\equiv t\ \imp\ x = {t \over \mu}\quad\mbox{and}\quad
>      \dd x={\ic + \verts{a} \over \verts{a}}\,\dd t}$
>   \begin{align}&\color{#c00000}{\int_{0}^{1}%
> {\ln\pars{1 + x} \over 1 + a^{2}x^{2}}\,\dd x}
> ={1 \over \verts{a}}\,
> \Im\bracks{-\int_{\mu}^{2\mu}%
> {\ln\pars{t/\mu} \over 1 - t}\,\dd t}
> \\[3mm]&={1 \over \verts{a}}\,\Im\bracks{%
> \ln\pars{1 - 2\mu}\ln\pars{2} - \int_{\mu}^{2\mu}{\ln\pars{1 - t} \over t}\,\dd t}
> \\[3mm]&={1 \over \verts{a}}\,\Im\bracks{%
> \ln\pars{1 - 2\mu}\ln\pars{2} + {\rm Li}_{2}\pars{2\mu} - {\rm Li}_{2}\pars{\mu}}
> \end{align}

$$\color{#c00000}{\int_{0}^{1}%
{\ln\pars{1 + x} \over 1 + a^{2}x^{2}}\,\dd x}
={1 \over \verts{a}}\,\Im\bracks{%
\ln\pars{\ic - \verts{a} \over \ic + \verts{a}}\ln\pars{2}
+{\rm Li}_{2}\pars{2\verts{a} \over \ic + \verts{a}}
-{\rm Li}_{2}\pars{\verts{a} \over \ic + \verts{a}}}
$$

> \begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large\int_{0}^{1}%
> {\ln\pars{1 + x} \over 1 + a^{2}x^{2}}\,\dd x}
> \\[3mm]&=\color{#66f}{\large2\ln\pars{2}\,{\arctan\pars{a} \over a}
> +{1 \over \verts{a}}\,\Im\bracks{%
> {\rm Li}_{2}\pars{2\verts{a} \over \ic + \verts{a}}
> -{\rm Li}_{2}\pars{\verts{a} \over \ic + \verts{a}}}}
> \end{align}

Answer (score 0):

A [related problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188732/methods-to-evaluate-int-a-b-frac-ln-left-tx-u-right-mx/188828#188828). Note that, the Legendre chi function is related to the polylogarithm by the [identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_chi_function)

> $$ \chi_\nu(z) = \frac{1}{2}\left[\operatorname{Li}_\nu(z) - \operatorname{Li}_\nu(-z)\right]. $$