# Integrating $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{(\log x)^2}{x^2+x+1}$ using residue theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals, residue-calculus

Just out of curiosity, how does one integrate something like this using residue theory?

> $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{(\log x)^2}{x^2+x+1} dx$$

According to Wolfram Alpha, the [answer](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20log%28x%29%5E2%20/%20%28x%5E2%2bx%2b1%29%20from%20x=0%20to%20infty) is $\dfrac{16\pi^3}{81\sqrt{3}}$.

I have seen similar integrals before, like [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/177160/integral-int-infty-infty-frac-lnx21x21dx?lq=1) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/186142/integral-int-infty-infty-frac-lnt1t21-mathrmdt?rq=1), and they all require seem some sort of ingenuity. I am sure [local Ramanujans](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/390801/closed-form-for-sum-n-1-infty-frac12n-left1-sqrt2n2-right/390815#comment836383_390801) will come to rescue soon. :)

Comment: By change $x=e^t$ the integral under consideration is reduced to $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac {t^2e^t\,dt}{e^{2t}+e^t+1}.$$ Making use of residues, the one can be expressed as a series. I see only sporting interest in such things. BTW, this is 4.261.3 in Gradshtein and Ryzhik. They refer to an old book published in 1867.

Comment: @user64494: Thanks! After reading your comment, I found this great website: [here](http://129.81.170.14/~vhm/Table.html).  Amazing resource. Indeed, here is the [problem](http://129.81.170.14/~vhm/formula_html/4.261.3.pdf) above.

Comment: Integrate the function $$f(z)=\frac {\log^3 (z)}{z^2+z+1} $$ around a key-hole conotour indented around the origin with the branch cut along the positive x-axis.

Comment: [Dublicate](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/294541/a-generalized-integral-need-help).

Comment: By the way, I provided a general technique for solving this kind of integrals. See [my answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/294541/a-generalized-integral-need-help).

Answer (score 2):

Hint ;

Define the following function $$f(z)=\frac {\log^3 (z)}{z^2+z+1}$$ on a key-hole contour with branch cut on the positive real axis . The function has poles $z=e^{\frac{2\pi}{3}i},e^{\frac{4\pi}{3}i}$ .Since the function is analytic in and on the contour with the poles inside the contour we can use the residue theorem

$$\int^{\infty}_0 f(x)\, dx -\int^{\infty}_0 \frac{\left( \log(x)+ 2 \pi i \right)^3}{x^2+x+1}\, dx= 2\pi i \text{Res}\,\left( f(z) ; e^{\frac{2\pi}{3}i},e^{\frac{4\pi}{3}i}\right)$$

Note:We can easily prove that the integration around the small and big circles approaches $0$.

Note: the third power will cancel and the first power is equal to $0$.

Answer (score 1):

See: Glasser, Amer.Math.Monthly Vol.71,p.75 (1964)

Comment: Very good find!